# how can I use TOR in China

Tags: help

I am going to study in China and I want to know if TOR browser works in China and how can I configure it. (use gmail and google services)
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed tor browser :

1. Click Tor button (a button nearby address bar with an onion icon)
2. Select tor network settings
3. when window opened check the "My internet service provider blocks connections to tor network" checkbox
4. select transport type (for China use meek-azure or meek-amazon)
5. List item

click at ok and enjoy tor network

Answer (score 1):

For situations where Tor is blocked by a firewall, you can configure Tor Browser to use ShadowsocksR (SSR) as a proxy server. This short proof-of-concept video demonstrates the client configuration on Windows.

Tor浏览器+ShadowsocksR(SSR)客户端配置 Client Configuration

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VRGZ4dOYv1Q

Comment: Are there significant advantages to using Tor on top of Shadowsocks? Since Shadowsocks presumably already allows you to reach the blocked website you want without Tor in the first place.